# MySql: Select statement in one query to retrieve all data from one table and just one from another table

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to select all columns from table A and just one column from table B, the information is related so I tried to join tables, but didn't work.

The following setup can be used as example, note that genreId is a foreign key to tbGenres(id):

tbBooks

| id | title | genreId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'title1' | 4 |
| 2 | 'title2' | 4 |
| 3 | 'title3' | 2 |

tbGenres

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'Action' |
| 4 | 'Comedy' |

I want a query that gives me the following, based on the genre_id. So for example, when we pass 4 as param of the query:

| id | title | genreId | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'title1' | 4 | 'Comedy' |
| 2 | 'title2' | 4 | 'Comedy' |

I tried to use INNER JOIN and other JOINS with a WHERE clause, like this:

`SELECT a.*, b.name from tbBooks AS a INNER JOIN tbGenres AS b WHERE a.genreId = 4`

But it returned multiple repeated rows with incorrects tbGenres names.

Can someone help with this one? I also thought of using UNION but I can't since I don't have the same number of columns in both tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `INNER JOIN` clause with the correct `ON` condition. . Here is the corrected code:

```
SELECT a.*, b.name
FROM tbBooks AS a
INNER JOIN tbGenres AS b ON a.genreId = b.id
WHERE a.genreId = 4;
```

Here is the [fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/aFX9jsEa)

Answer (score 1):

Some comments on your question

'INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product' -https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

your query segment

```
SELECT a.*, b.name from tbBooks AS a INNER JOIN tbGenres AS b ;
```

results in

```
+------+--------+---------+--------+
| id   | title  | genreId | name   |
+------+--------+---------+--------+
|    1 | title1 |       4 | Action |
|    1 | title1 |       4 | Comedy |
|    2 | title2 |       4 | Action |
|    2 | title2 |       4 | Comedy |
|    3 | title3 |       2 | Action |
|    3 | title3 |       2 | Comedy |
+------+--------+---------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

with the condition

```
SELECT a.*, b.name from tbBooks AS a INNER JOIN tbGenres AS b WHERE a.genreId = 4;
```

results in

```
+------+--------+---------+--------+
| id   | title  | genreId | name   |
+------+--------+---------+--------+
|    1 | title1 |       4 | Action |
|    1 | title1 |       4 | Comedy |
|    2 | title2 |       4 | Action |
|    2 | title2 |       4 | Comedy |
+------+--------+---------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Changing the condition to

```
SELECT a.*, b.name from tbBooks AS a INNER JOIN tbGenres AS b WHERE a.genreId = 4 and (a.genreid = b.id);

+------+--------+---------+--------+
| id   | title  | genreId | name   |
+------+--------+---------+--------+
|    1 | title1 |       4 | Comedy |
|    2 | title2 |       4 | Comedy |
+------+--------+---------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

but the better code is supplied in the answer from @User12345

a UNION is a a vertical join and not the result you want AND you are wrong to think you cannot union tables with different number of columns, you can supply dummy values if need be. You also should name columns rather than use *

```
select a.* from tbBooks a where genreid = 4
union
select b.ID,b.name,'' from tbGenres b where id = 4;

+------+--------+---------+
| id   | title  | genreId |
+------+--------+---------+
|    1 | title1 | 4       |
|    2 | title2 | 4       |
|    4 | Comedy |         |
+------+--------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Even though I didn't accepted your answer, it was really helpful to learn some concepts that I didn't know until reading what you wrote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this query will also work:

```
select a.*, b.name from tbBooks a join tbGenres b on a.genreId=b.id where id = 4;
```

Comment: If you see this answer, I also have a doubt. In question you've also mentioned that `genreId` is referred as a foreign key for `id` in `tbGenres` table. Is it possible that referencing a non-unique or non-primary key as a foreign key. (If I am wrong please correct me).

Comment: I didn't have any problem in referencing a non-primary Key as a foreign key, and in fact a table can have more than one declaration of a foreign key, but a table can have only one primary Key. You answer is not correct because the condition must be there for the query work the way I need (passed dynamically as a param and filtering the results)